# Python 2.7 cannot install modules after El Capitan upgrade

Tags: python

After upgrading my MacOS to El Capita 10.11.6, I cannot run my code because of missing imports.

This one works

```
$ python -m  pip install --user six
```

But this one fails to install the module.

```
$ sudo pip install six
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Users/mpme/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

Could someone let me know the differences ? Why one works and the other does not?

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Comment: reinstall pip, see what happens

Comment: Don't use `sudo pip`.  That's never correct.

Comment: I think it has to do with SIP, read more here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/how-to-use-pip-after-the-os-x-el-capitan-upgrade